# Ipad issue : Selecting a video using UIImagePickerController and UIPopoverController

Tags: video, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

this is my first ever question.

I am developing a iPad app that allows a user to select a video, trim it and then choose it.  I first prototyped it for the iPhone and everything work fine.  I then ported the code to the iPad, changed the modelviewcontroller for a popupviewcontroller and I get a odd problem.  There is no choose button, only a play button.  So the popup works, you can go to a video, but only a play icon exists, no choose?   The exact same code for the iphone shows a choose?  Have I missed something?

```
// Settings for the picker

imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

imagePicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];  

//settings for the popup

UIPopoverController *controller2 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

self.popoverVideoSelectController = controller2;
 [controller2 release];

[self.popoverVideoSelectController presentPopoverFromRect:loadVideo1Button.frame inView:videoToolsLeft permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was adding my own toolbarbutton which was replacing the use one